# Complex conjugate of a delta function

Tags: distribution-theory

How should we regard to the complex conjugate of a Dirac delta function? I mean, is the observation that
$\left(\delta(x)\right)^{\ast}\neq\delta(x),\quad\left(\Theta(x)\right)^{\ast}\neq\Theta(x)$

generally correct? Obviously, the singular point, when $x=0$, cannot be regarded as real element.

Comment: What is your definition of a complex conjugate for distributions? The most obvious I can think of would be $\delta^*(f) = f^*(0) $ which would coincide with $\delta$ on any real space of test functions.

Comment: Mabye this can help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3373078/conjugate-of-dirac-delta

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: It is a good question which I'm not sure about. My real intension is to know if some Hamiltonian that contains distributions should be considered as Hermitian or not.

Comment: I would define $\langle u^*, \phi \rangle = \langle u, \phi^* \rangle^*$ for any distribution $u$ based upon how it works for functions. That would make $\delta^*=\delta$ and $\Theta^*=\Theta.$

Comment: @md2perpe But, in principle, it seems also fine to define $\left\langle u^{\ast},\phi\right\rangle =\left\langle u,\phi\right\rangle ^{\ast}$, right? is there any way to determine what is the consistent way of dealing with these objects or is it just a matter of definitions that we can play with?

Comment: If $\phi$ is real-valued then that is okay. Suppose that $u$ is an ordinary function (e.g. $L^1_{\text{loc}}$) and $\phi$ is complex-valued. Then,
$$\langle u^*, \phi \rangle = \int u(x)^* \, \phi(x) \, dx = \left( \int u(x) \, \phi(x)^* \, dx \right)^*.$$
We want to define $u^*$ so that this special case holds.

Comment: @md2perpe: But for example, the action of the conjugate Dirac delta as in Brevan's comment above (the first comment) is defined as if the 'star is acting only once'. Is one definition better than the other? in other words, am I obliged to use a specific definition?

Comment: @md2perpe By the way, regardless of my previous comment, you agree that the operator that I defined by $\mathcal{N}$ in the draft the I sent you is non-trivial is the Hamiltonian is either unbounded or complex, right?

Comment: The definition given by @BrevanEllefsen isn't even linear. Take $f=f_r+if_i,$ where $f_r,f_i$ are real.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't intend to say what I was proposing is the best (or even a reasonable) definition by any means, merely that you need to fix a definition for your question to make sense.

Comment: @md2perpe: well.. his definition is anti-linear which still make sense (at least for me), since the conjugation operation is non-linear. The main point is that unlike the case of regular complex numbers, the generalization of conjugation from complex numbers to distributions is not something obvious. So, a Hamiltonian defined by distributions should not really be regarded as an Hermitian.

Comment: Since it's not linear, it's not a distribution.

Comment: @md2perpe About that I completely agree. Anyway, I am not saying anything against your definition :)